# Traverse HTML to JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I've created a function that will traverse anykind of JSON data into UL/ LI's. Now I need to do the opposite and convert the UL/LI's back into JSON Objects. I'd like to do this in JQuery if possible. So how do i turn my Nested UL/LI's back into its original JSON object?

```
var traverseJson = function(jsonObj) {
  "use strict";
  var htmlOut = "",
    value,
    inputv,
    prop;
  for (prop in jsonObj) {
    if (jsonObj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
      value = jsonObj[prop];
      switch (typeof value){
        case "object":
          htmlOut += "<li><b>" + prop + "</b><span>" + traverseJson(value) + "</span></li>";
          break;
        default:
          inputv = "<span>" + value  + "</span>";
          htmlOut += "<li class='val'><b>" + prop + ":</b>" + inputv + "</li>";
          break;
      }
    }
  }
  return "<ul>" + htmlOut + "</ul>";
};
```

Comment: Not sure if you guys realized this was a recursive function. Somehow I'll need to check if it's a UL or LI don't i?

Comment: I cleaned up the code a little bit using [JSHint](http://www.jshint.com/). A few thing that needed to be fixed. When you use `for ... in` you should always [filter the loop](http://yuiblog.com/blog/2006/09/26/for-in-intrigue/) using `.hasOwnProperty`. Also since you never declared `prop` it became an [implicit global](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html). `self` is not a keyword in JS, you can just call `traverseJson` since it is already in your scope. If `traverseJson` was a method of an object you could use `this.traverseJson` to refer to it instead.

Comment: Thanks Useless, i saw your edits live almost. Good points!

Comment: @karthikr actually read the question that doesn't solve it at all. The existing code works, the OP is asking for help with a function that does the opposite of this code.

Answer (score 2):

Well what you have to do is to iterate through li elements.

```
function parseList() {
    var outObj = {};

    $("li").each(function () {
        var propName = $(this).children("b").html();
        var propValue = $(this).children("span").html();
        outObj[propName] = propValue;
    });

    return outObj;
}
```

Comment: I think this is part of it, but i need to traverse it infinitely down. cuz it could have objects in objects...

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work. It takes a a jQuery object representing a div and finds the first `ul` tag inside it and traverses down until it finds `li` tags that don't contain a `ul` tag.

```
var divToJson = function ($div) {
  "use strict";
  var traverseUl = function ($ul) {
    var  output = {},
      $li = $ul.children('li');
    $li.each(function () {
      var $this = $(this),
        propName = $this.children('b').text(),
        $propValue = $this.children('span'),
        $subList = $propValue.find('ul').first();

        if ($subList.length > 0) {
          output[propName] = traverseUl($subList);
        } else {
          output[propName] = $propValue.text();
        }
    });
    return output;
  };

  return traverseUl($div.find('ul').first());
}; 

var theDiv = $('#somediv');
console.log(divToJson(theDiv));
```